# Header freeze when I use data-scroll-section

Tags: html

I build a page web with a header who  have 100vw ana 100vh

[My header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6b4f.jpg)

I had locomotive scroll  on my page but when I had "data-scroll-section"
on a section my page freeze I ts impossible to scroll down to view the content on my page

```html
 <div class="enseigne" data-scroll-section>
          <h2>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="2">c</span>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="3">h</span>
<span  data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="4">e</span>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="5">z</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="6">m</span>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="7">e</span>
<span data-scroll data-scroll-repeat data-scroll-speed="9">d</span>
 
          </h2>
     </div>
```

here my complete html code:
[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/PL57J6Xe)

my css code:
[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/vJTjGM3E)

I'm trying to realise this effect at 10.34 min
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-ks1-dzKEw&t=604s)

thanks by advance for any answer.